# How to properly ensure a custom UITableViewCell can be reused

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that is rendering out a custom `UITableViewCell`'.

This cells are related to chat messages, as such the config is almost identical, apart from how the elements are constrained.

> bot cell is: *avatar > message*
>
> user cell is *message < avatar*

I was hoping to combine these in a single custom cell and simply switch on an `origin` property on the model, allowing me to choose which constraints I am applying.

This worked for 5 or 6 messages, until however I ran a test with 30 messages and some cells started to inherit both sets of anchors or even just random properties that should be assigned to the other cell.

I can see the errors suggest the constraints are invalid and I believe this is due to the cell not being prepared for reuse correctly.

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002533930 UIImageView:0x7fb401514d40.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600003f18e00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002526990 UITextView:0x7fb40200a200'I am a Person.'.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600003f18e00'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading + 15   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000025271b0 UITextView:0x7fb40200a200'I am a Person.'.trailing == UIImageView:0x7fb401514d40.leading - 15   (active)>"
)
```

**ChatMessageCell**

```
class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    fileprivate var content: ChatMessage? {
        didSet {
            guard let text = content?.text else { return }
            messageView.text = text
            
            guard let origin = content?.origin else { return }
            setupSubViews(origin)
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate var messageAvatar: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 35 / 2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()
    
    fileprivate var messageView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isSelectable = false
        textView.sizeToFit()
        textView.layoutIfNeeded()
        textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 10)
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        textView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textView
    }()
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setContent(as content: ChatMessage) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        content = nil
    }
}

extension ChatMessageCell {
    fileprivate func setupSubViews(_ origin: ChatMessageOrigin) {
        let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        [messageAvatar, messageView].forEach { v in contentView.addSubview(v) }
        
        switch origin {
        case .system:
            messageAvatar.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "large-bot-head")
            messageAvatar.anchor(
                top: margins.topAnchor, leading: margins.leadingAnchor, size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
            )
            messageView.anchor(
                top: margins.topAnchor, leading: messageAvatar.trailingAnchor, bottom: margins.bottomAnchor, trailing: margins.trailingAnchor,
                padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
            )
        case .user:
            let userContentBG = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "00f5ff")
            messageAvatar.image = UIImage.from(color: userContentBG)
            messageAvatar.anchor(
                top: margins.topAnchor, trailing: margins.trailingAnchor, size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
            )
            messageView.layer.backgroundColor = userContentBG.cgColor
            messageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
            messageView.anchor(
                top: margins.topAnchor, leading: margins.leadingAnchor, bottom: margins.bottomAnchor, trailing: messageAvatar.leadingAnchor,
                padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**ChatController**

```
class ChatController: UITableViewController {
    lazy var viewModel: ChatViewModel = {
        let viewModel = ChatViewModel()
        return viewModel
    }()
    
    fileprivate let headerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        viewModel.reloadData = { [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

        configureViewHeader()
        configureTableView()
        registerTableCells()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.history.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = viewModel.history[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withClass: ChatMessageCell.self)
        cell.setContent(as: item)
        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell
    }
}

extension ChatController {
    fileprivate func configureViewHeader() {
        let margins = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        view.addSubview(headerView)
        headerView.anchor(
            top: margins.topAnchor, leading: margins.leadingAnchor, trailing: margins.trailingAnchor,
            size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 70)
        )
    }
    
    fileprivate func configureTableView() {
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
    
    fileprivate func registerTableCells() {
        tableView.register(cellWithClass: ChatMessageCell.self)
    }
}
```

An example of how the view changes on scroll can be seen here....
[image: Pre scroll]
[image: Post scroll]

My Extensions are applied with

```
  @discardableResult
    func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> AnchoredConstraints {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var anchoredConstraints = AnchoredConstraints()
        
        if let top = top {
            anchoredConstraints.top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
        }
        
        if let leading = leading {
            anchoredConstraints.leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
        }
        
        if let bottom = bottom {
            anchoredConstraints.bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
        }
        
        if let trailing = trailing {
            anchoredConstraints.trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
        }
        
        if size.width != 0 {
            anchoredConstraints.width = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
        }
        
        if size.height != 0 {
            anchoredConstraints.height = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
        }
        
        [anchoredConstraints.top, anchoredConstraints.leading, anchoredConstraints.bottom, anchoredConstraints.trailing, anchoredConstraints.width, anchoredConstraints.height].forEach { $0?.isActive = true }
        
        return anchoredConstraints
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ChatMessageCell` class, move:

```
[messageAvatar, messageView].forEach { v in contentView.addSubview(v) }
```

from `setupSubViews(...)` to `init(...)`. With your current code, `setupSubViews` is being called every time you set the content. You only want to add the subviews to the cell's `contentView` when the cell is initialized.

From there, you need to check how you're adding constraints. If your `.anchor(...)` func / extension is first removing any existing constraints, you should be ok.

---

**Edit:**

Here is another option - you may find it easier to work with.

Since you have the same subviews, set up two arrays of constraints. Then activate or deactivate the appropriate set (as well as setting colors, corners, etc):

```
class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    fileprivate var content: ChatMessage? {
        didSet {
            guard let text = content?.text else { return }
            messageView.text = text

            guard let origin = content?.origin else { return }
            setupSubViews(origin)
        }
    }

    fileprivate var messageAvatar: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 35 / 2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    fileprivate var messageView: UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isSelectable = false
        textView.sizeToFit()
        textView.layoutIfNeeded()
        textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 10, bottom: 5, right: 10)
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textView
    }()

    fileprivate var systemConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    fileprivate var userConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func setContent(as content: ChatMessage) {
        self.content = content
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        backgroundColor = .clear

        let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        [messageAvatar, messageView].forEach { v in contentView.addSubview(v) }

        systemConstraints = [
            messageAvatar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            messageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageAvatar.trailingAnchor, constant: 15.0),
            messageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: -15),
        ]

        userConstraints = [
            messageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor, constant: 15.0),

            messageAvatar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            messageAvatar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 15),
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // messageAvatar width/height/top is the same for each origin "type"
            messageAvatar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            messageAvatar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35),
            messageAvatar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35),

            // messageView width/height/top is the same for each origin "type"
            messageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.topAnchor, constant: 5.0),
            messageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            ])

    }

}

extension ChatMessageCell {
    fileprivate func setupSubViews(_ origin: ChatMessageOrigin) {

        switch origin {
        case .system:
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(userConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(systemConstraints)
            messageView.backgroundColor = .white
            messageAvatar.backgroundColor = .red
            messageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]

        default:
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(systemConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(userConstraints)
            messageView.backgroundColor = .cyan
            messageAvatar.backgroundColor = .blue
            messageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]

        }

    }
}
```

Note: I'm using Swift 4.1, so there are a couple of syntax changes (but they'll be obvious).

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't seem to help, I will update my answer with my .anchor extension now

Comment: @HarryBlue - looks like you need to modify your `.anchor()` extension to remove any existing constraints before adding the new ones.

Answer (score 0):

When you have two different layouts of cells, having two different classes of cells would be another way to handle your issue.

**ChatMessageCell**

```
class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    fileprivate var content: ChatMessage? {
        didSet {
            guard let text = content?.text else { return }
            messageView.text = text
        }
    }

    //...    

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        setupSubViews()
    }
    fileprivate func setupSubViews() {
        [messageAvatar, messageView].forEach { v in contentView.addSubview(v) }
    }

    //...
}

class UserMessageCell: ChatMessageCell {
    fileprivate override func setupSubViews() {
        super.setupSubViews()
        let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        let userContentBG = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "00f5ff")
        messageAvatar.image = UIImage.from(color: userContentBG)
        messageAvatar.anchor(
            top: margins.topAnchor, trailing: margins.trailingAnchor, size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        )
        messageView.layer.backgroundColor = userContentBG.cgColor
        messageView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
        messageView.anchor(
            top: margins.topAnchor, leading: margins.leadingAnchor, bottom: margins.bottomAnchor, trailing: messageAvatar.leadingAnchor,
            padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        )
    }
}

class SystemMessageCell: ChatMessageCell {
    fileprivate override func setupSubViews() {
        super.setupSubViews()
        let margins = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        messageAvatar.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "large-bot-head")
        messageAvatar.anchor(
            top: margins.topAnchor, leading: margins.leadingAnchor, size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        )
        messageView.anchor(
            top: margins.topAnchor, leading: messageAvatar.trailingAnchor, bottom: margins.bottomAnchor, trailing: margins.trailingAnchor,
            padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)
        )
    }
}
```

**ChatController**

```
class ChatController: UITableViewController {
    //...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = viewModel.history[indexPath.row]
        let cell: ChatMessageCell
        switch item.origin {
        case .system:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withClass: SystemMessageCell.self)
        case .user:
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withClass: UserMessageCell.self)
        }
        cell.setContent(as: item)
        cell.layoutSubviews()
        return cell
    }
}

extension ChatController {
    //...

    fileprivate func registerTableCells() {
        tableView.register(cellWithClass: SystemMessageCell.self)
        tableView.register(cellWithClass: UserMessageCell.self)
    }
}
```